# Add unique words from a text file to a list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

suppose I have the following text file:

> ```
> But soft what light through yonder window breaks
> It is the east and Juliet is the sun
> Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
> Who is already sick and pale with grief
> ```

I want to add all unique words in this file to a list

```
fname = open("romeo.txt")
lst = list()
for line in fname:
    line = line.rstrip()
    words = line.split(' ')
    for word in words:
        if word in lst: continue
        lst = lst + words
    lst.sort()
print lst
```

but the optupt of the program is as follows:

```
['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 
'and', 'and', 'breaks', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 
'is', 'is', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick', 
'soft', 'sun', 'sun', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'through', 'what', 
'window', 'with', 'yonder']
```

**'and'** and a few other words appear multiple times in the list. Which part of the loop should I change, so that I don't have any duplicate words? Thanks!

Comment: You are appending all words if you do `lst = lst + words`, `do lst.append(word)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the problems with your code and a corrected version follows:

```
fname = open("romeo.txt")      # better to open files in a `with` statement
lst = list()                   # lst = [] is more Pythonic
for line in fname:
    line = line.rstrip()       # not required, `split()` will do this anyway
    words = line.split(' ')    # don't specify a delimiter, `line.split()` will split on all white space
    for word in words:
        if word in lst: continue
        lst = lst + words      # this is the reason that you end up with duplicates... words is the list of all words for this line!
    lst.sort()                 # don't sort in the for loop, just once afterwards.
print lst
```

So it almost works, however, you should be appending only the current `word` to the list, not all of the `words` that you got from the line with `split()`. If you simply changed the line:

```
lst = lst + words
```

to

```
lst.append(word)
```

it will work.

Here is a corrected version:

```
with open("romeo.txt") as infile:
    lst = []
    for line in infile:
        words = line.split()
        for word in words:
            if word not in lst:
                lst.append(word)    # append only this word to the list, not all words on this line
    lst.sort()
    print(lst)
```

As others have suggested, a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set) is a good way to handle this. This is about as simple as it gets:

```
with open('romeo.txt') as infile:
    print(sorted(set(infile.read().split())))
```

Using `sorted()` you don't need to keep a reference to the list. If you do want to use the sorted list elsewhere, just do this:

```
with open('romeo.txt') as infile:
    unique_words = sorted(set(infile.read().split()))
    print(unique_words)
```

Reading the entire file into memory may not be viable for large files. You can use a *generator* to efficiently read the file without cluttering up the main code. This generator will read the file one line at a time and it will yield one word at a time. It will not read the entire file in one go, unless the file consists of one long line (which your sample data clearly doesn't):

```
def get_words(f):
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            yield word

with open('romeo.txt') as infile:
    unique_words = sorted(set(get_words(infile)))
```

Answer (score 4):

This is much easier in python using sets:

```
with open("romeo.txt") as f:
     unique_words = set(f.read().split())
```

If you want to have a list,  convert it afterwards:

```
 unique_words = list(unique_words)
```

Might be nice to have them in alphabeitcal order:

```
unique_words.sort()
```

Comment: It is easier, but it doesn't answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to achieve what you want.
1) Using lists:

```
fname = open("romeo.txt")
lst = list()
for word in fname.read().split(): # This will split by all whitespace, meaning that it will spilt by ' ' and '\n'
    if word not in lst:
        lst.append(word)
lst.sort()
print lst
```

2) Using sets:

```
fname = open("romeo.txt")
lst = list(set(fname.read().split()))
lst.sort()
print lst
```

Set simply ignores the duplicates, so the check is unneccesary

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a set of unique words, you better use `set`, not `list`, since `in lst` may be highly inefficient.

For counting words you better use [`Counter` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) .

Comment: I think you mean "inefficient", not "ineffective". `in lst` will be _effective_, but it will likely be slow.

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
with open('romeo.txt') as fname:
    text = fname.read()
    lst = list(set(text.split()))
    print lst


>> ['and', 'envious', 'already', 'fair', 'is', 'through', 'pale', 'yonder', 'what', 'sun', 'Who', 'But', 'moon', 'window', 'sick', 'east', 'breaks', 'grief', 'with', 'light', 'It', 'Arise', 'kill', 'the', 'soft', 'Juliet']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `word` instead of `words` (also simplified the loop)

```
fname = open("romeo.txt")
lst = list()
for line in fname:
    line = line.rstrip()
    words = line.split(' ')
    for word in words:
        if word not in lst:
            lst.append(word)
    lst.sort()
print lst
```

or alternately use `[word]` with `+` operator

```
fname = open("romeo.txt")
lst = list()
for line in fname:
    line = line.rstrip()
    words = line.split(' ')
    for word in words:
        if word in lst: continue
        lst = lst + [word]
    lst.sort()
print lst
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to change

`lst = lst + words` to `lst.append(word)`

If you want unique words you need to add `word` and not `words` ( which is all words in line) to the list.